# how to fix auth with sessions?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have some .sessions for telethon, I can't auth them, because "Please enter your phone (or bot token): ". I don't use proxy. How to fix it? I can give you my files. Sessions geo - Indonesia

I used different sessions, but work only 1

Comment: Please improve the question by including the code you've written and other details we should know to be able to help you.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)